# Does this water pipe installation have problem?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I just bought a new home which is still under construction. Today I visited the home and noticed that the water pipe installation at one place seems awkward!

It's on the main floor and actually the connector is slightly above the OSB subfloor!

Is it OK? Does this installation possibly violate any kind of code ?

[image: Water Pipe Installation Problem?]

Comment: It violates the code of "in a neat and workmanlike manner". This phrase is in the electrical code and I am just assuming it is also in the plumbing code. This looks like a real hack job.

Comment: Plumbing by "Hack'n Slash" coming to a contracting MMORPG near you. Dual tool wielding encouraged, get 'R done fast, pay for the short cut many times over during the years. But seriously, it's poor planning and workmanship and introduces multiple points of failure in what should be a straight run. No excuse for this with PEX.

Comment: What flooring are they installing? Hopefully it's self supporting material like tile (with backerboard) or solid hardwood. Otherwise the risk just of damage when weight is placed (if something like laminate/engineered wood, vinyl, carpet, etc is put over it) is too great. Also, it reeks of poor judgment, looks like they cut the pex line wrong and said "welp this is where the connector is going to go"

Comment: It will be 9/16 hardwood floor.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYBODY!   I have raised the concerns to builder. And also I am going to the county and show them the pictures.  Not sure whether I will be able to talk to the inspector who is supposed to check the house directly. BTW, the house is being built by "American #1 Builder"..... Good thing is we get chance to observe such internal works. I even start to worry about neighbors who bought their constructed home.

Comment: Just got replay from builder. **"pipes in floor due to beam below. Not able to drill beam below. Structural integrity issues if drilled."**

Comment: TOTAL GARBAGE! At an absolute minimum, it should be moved to the inside of that wall & be behind the shower pan or tub there (I'm presuming) where it'll never be under surface threat & would then be drilled through the joist or composite beam from the other side. But, by all rights it should go way right or left to the next perpendicular wall where it can drop down between joists & then be drilled through the center of this joist or composite beam to be brought back to this point & continue below. What happens if it gets banned like Poly Butyl Pipe, the previous "wonder" plastic plumbing.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting and suggestions. Seller agree to terminate the contract and return all the money. So it's a good ending.

Comment: NO SH..! Wow! Yeah, you absolutely don't want a house from him or them! If he/they are willing to back out of a done deal because you have eyes, a mouth & common sense, then there's no telling what you can't see. For maybe $200, at the worst, he could've addressed it & had a future referral. I'm sorry, but I'm more glad he/they showed their true colors. Phenomenal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with ArchonOSX, it's very sloppy & does violate code beyond that. It needs to be re-done & even when it's right it should have a metal plate bridging more than its width so nails or screws can't penetrate it for just that bottom stud.

The jog they did has to be a minimum of 1-1/2-inches away from the underside of the floor, again so penetrations can't or aren't likely to happen. It doesn't matter how far back they have to start over with the line or where they have to move it to in order to do it right, it has to be safe from potential damage.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should ask the plumber if they have a reason for doing this the way they did. Perhaps you have a floor joist in the way and the plumbing will be under the toekick of the cabinet. It would have been much more work for the plumber to do things this way than to come straight up the wall so im sure there is more here than meets the eye.

Comment: Reading the other comments, none of those things you mention are good reasons for bad workmanship like this.  Even if there are things in the way, there are better ways to do this work and it's not just the placement that is the issue here - there are concerns about the fact that it's flush with the flooring - even if it's never going to be seen, it should still be protected.